# Error Parsing 'Gemfile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a learning rails project on

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

I am on the Rails Example Applications section, but when I run

```
bundle install --without production
```

I receive this error:

```
 [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot - ruby ‘2.3.0’
              ^
    /Users/eric.park/workspace/learn-rails/Gemfile:2: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting '('
    ruby ‘2.3.0’
                 ^. Bundler cannot continue.

     #  from /Users/eric.park/workspace/learn-rails/Gemfile:2
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
     >  ruby ‘2.3.0’
     #  gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
     #  -------------------------------------------
```

I am new to rails, so if anyone can explain what this error generally means, and how I can address it if it shows up again that would be really helpful.

Comment: I was using a theme, and this line in `Gemfile` was breaking the build for me `gemspec` (I hadn't copied across the .gemspec file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the quotation problem.

Try manually typing the sentence again with either single quote or double quote.

`ruby '2.3.0'` or `ruby "2.3.0"`

This should fix it.

Comment: I recently realized this! Thanks, but what made the default gem file include two different types of quotes?

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere else? I had the same problem before when I copied the code from a website.

Comment: The GitHub repo for the example application contained the error. It's now corrected: https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/pull/78

Comment: TextEdit does weird things, if another line works copy/paste that quote character and re-use it.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you copy and pasted code into a Gemfile that you say, created with textedit, unidentified syntax and formatting are also inherent with the copy, and therefore my solution was to open a completely blank document, or write it direct in VIM etc, and type from scratch - do not copy and paste code, otherwise you risk copying over unintentional formatting and imbedded syntax that you might not be able to see.